# Laravel: why is cache data binary?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm not sure, but I think that the data that gets stored using `Cache::remember` is binary. It looks something like this and continues on: `3133 3632 3334 3838 3533 613a 343a 7b73`.

Why is it encoded / binary / whatever it is?

Edit: I'm currently using file cache cause database cache is giving me errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking at is an encoded encrypted cache

All cache is derived from `Store.php`. `DatabaseStore.php` is the only method where the store function includes an encryption. The Laravel database cache source code includes this comment:

> All of the cached values in the database are encrypted in case this is used as a session data store by the consumer

In otherwords, if your database was compromised - the data is protected in theory if they do not have access to your source code as well.

The cache uses your secret key (defined in `app.php`) as the passphrase to encrypt/decrypt this key. The encryption occurs in the `Encrypter.php` file, which is called by the inheritied store file (i.e. DatabaseStore.php) during get/set cache calls.

Edit: as a demo - the following File cache

```
Cache::remember('test', 5, function()
{
    return 'example';
});
```

results in

```
 1362413945s:1:"example";
```

Comment: You're talking about cookies, but I'm not. Not sure if we're on the same page :). I'm using `Cache` to cache some HTML. So no cookies at work there. And I was wondering why this cache, that really doesn't have to be encrypted, is encrypted. It introduces additional overhead and also means, that I can't use this cache without `Cache`.

Comment: Sorry - I've fixed my answer for you

Comment: I have upvoted, but not (yet) accepted. I'm using file cache (I've updated my question now). You say that db cache is the only one encrypted. Maybe this isn't true (anymore)? Or is something else at work?

Comment: No - there is something else going on with your server/setup. I tested this - and a file cache gives a php serialized array. So you might have some code elsewhere doing something to the cache? Or perhaps are you using something like APC?

Comment: Weird, then it must be something on my setup. But nothing else is changing the cache. No APC either. Thanks for the help though.